# Are there any other unique items in TF2 other than Top Notch?

Tags: team-fortress-2

[Top Notch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Top_Notch) is an item currently existing as only a single copy, owned by Notch (of course).

Are there any other limited or unique items in either TF2?  ("Limited" meaning items which were only ever available in a fixed quantity, i.e. there was never a time when they were freely available.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [J.Axer's Dapper Topper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/J.Axer's_Dapper_Topper), [Amber's Rad as All Hell Hat](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Amber's_Rad_As_All_Hell_Hat) and [Uncle Sam](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Uncle_Sam) are unique. There is only one of each, and they were awarded to the first, second and third place winners in the Propaganda Contest.

Some items were gifted in Self-Made quality to their creators. Where an item was credited to a single creator, the Self-Made version of that is the only one in that quality, although this isn't as truly unique as the item is more widely available in normal quality.

Other than the [Top Notch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Top_Notch), these are the only one-of-a-kind items in TF2.

Other rare items (fewer than 1,000 awarded) include:

- Highlander tournament medals (no more than 9 of each, except for participant medals)

  - Gamers with Jobs tournament (1st, 2nd, and participant medal)
  - ETF2L Highlander tournament (1st, 2nd, 3rd and participant medal)
  - UGC Highlander tournament (1st, 2nd and 3rd for each of Platinum, Silver and Iron divisions, and a participant medal)
- the [Saxxy](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Saxxy) ([35 awarded](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_Saxxy_owners))
- the [Golden Wrench](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/The_Golden_Wrench) ([101 awarded](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_Golden_Wrench_owners), of which no more than 82 still exist)
- the [Polycount Pin](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Polycount_Pin) ([92 awarded](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_Polycount_Pin_owners))
- the [Wiki Cap](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/The_Wiki_Cap) ([112 awarded](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_Wiki_Cap_owners) to date)
- the [Hat of Undeniable Wealth and Respect](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Hat_of_Undeniable_Wealth_And_Respect) ([622 still exist](http://www.tf2items.com/lists/wealth/))
- [Valve weapons](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Valve_(quality)) (available to Valve staff only)

Comment: TellTale Games' staff each seem to have a Community Max's Severed Head.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it somewhat depends on how "unique" an item has to be.  For instance, there are certain versions of weapons that are given to key community members, or to the person who actually created the item.  Valve employees also have a special class of weapon that is reserved for them.  There's a [page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Quality) on the TF2Wiki that describes these and links to some lists.

There's also the weapons made of [Australium](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Australium), including the [Golden Wrench](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Golden_Wrench) and the [Saxxy](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Saxxy), of which there are very, very few.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, these are just normal items with a fancier name and a glow and at most minor variations. The Top Notch instead is a completely new model+skin.

Comment: Like I mentioned, "unique" is kind of a relative term.  TF2 even has a class of items called "unique" that are decidedly non-unique by pretty much any standards.  If your requirements are that there is only one and it has a custom model+skin, I don't know of any others besides the Top Notch.  However, those item variants are different enough that you *could* consider them unique, or at the very least exceedingly rare.

Comment: I guess the Saxxy qualifies, though.

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://tf2stats.net/items/) *(As of 2019, this site has gone down. You may be able to find another website that has information on backpack item frequency.)* scans backpacks and keeps stats of items. If you choose a category, not only can you see the relative popularity of items, but if you scroll all the way to the bottom you can see some rare items are owned by less than 0.01% of the players in their database.

In addition to [Jonathan Drain's list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38637/29694), some more interesting items:

- [Dueler](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dueler) - there's only 1 of this hat, but the owner may change each day, awarded for winning the most duels the day before
- [Lo-Fi Longwave](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Lo-Fi_Longwave) - unspecified number of them, awarded for subscribing to a podcast group
- [Holiday Headcase](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Holiday_Headcase) - randomly obtained from during the Steam Holiday Sale 2011, via crafting 7 Holiday Coal, or for earning achievements